# What is the equivalent of *NgFor in TypeScript for read/get data

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

I try to get/show data in TypeScript when i click on button. But I can show data only one time. I begin and i don't understant all thing. (sry for my english)

I already try to use forEach, but that work only one time.

```
   async spotAdded() {
    this.spots = this.spotService.getSpots(); // i get my data from here
    this.spots.forEach(info => {
      info.forEach(infos => {
        console.log(infos);
        const marker: Marker = this.map.addMarkerSync({
        position: {
          lat: infos.lat,
         lng: infos.lng
          },
        title: infos.description,
        snippet: infos.user,
        disableAutoPan: true
        });
        marker.showInfoWindow();
        });
    });
}
```

I actually have this but only one time for each spots there is in database (i using firebase) :

{id: "NbtJraND8XhSDUG8rlRY", createdAt: 1559308376871, description: "Quatre", flat: false, lat: 48.996672, …}

Comment: ngFor renders given data, forEach just iterate through it.
So, maybe you should store the given data somewhere and them on each onClick - show it with forEach.